# how to rotate imageview from its centre position that other layout images also animate

Tags: android, android-layout

i want to  rotate imageView1 from its centre position other image also move
my layout is

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="86dp"
    android:src="@drawable/top_pati" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:src="@drawable/top_pativertical" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:src="@drawable/top_pativertical" />
```

imageView3 is `android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"` and `android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"` when imageView1 animate then why my `imageView2` and `imageView3` not follow these images

I animate like this

```
RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0, 15, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                    0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            anim.setDuration(500);
            anim.setFillEnabled(true);
            anim.setFillAfter(true);
            imageView.startAnimation(anim);
            setuplayout();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far animation is concerned try this ..

```
@Override
        public void show() {
            super.show();
            RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 360.0f , Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, .5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, .5f);
            anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
            anim.setDuration(3000);
            iv.setAnimation(anim);
            iv.startAnimation(anim);
        }
```

When you need to use this  animation then try some thing like this ..

```
your_inatance_image.show();
```